# openssl_x509_parse returning false

Tags: php, pki, x509

I'm pulling a user certificate and attempting to use their information to log them in.  This is what I have so far.  Running on Apache with PHP I'm able to echo the $_SERVER variable which is an array that holds a variety of information about the user including what I'm assuming to be the client certificate.

I'm even able to run the following command:

```
echo($_SERVER['HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_CERT']);
```

the line above outputs the whole:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- BLAH...BLAH...BLAH -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

However if I run the following command:

```
$cert_data = openssl_x509_parse($_SERVER['HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_CERT']);
```

It returns false and I can't seem to get anything out of it.

I've tried:
**openssl_x509_read** as well to no avail.

I'm wondering if I need a new line after the:
**-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----**
because it seems as though the certificate is just one big long line of text.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After revisiting the problem it turns out that I needed to add the following line to the Apache httpd.conf file

```
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
```

Hope that helps someone.